# Create assoc array from array of asoc array

Tags: php

How can I create new array with structure: [id] => [prop] from data like this

```
$foo = array(
    array('id' => 2, 'prop' => 'val2'),
    array('id' => 1, 'prop' => 'val1'),
    array('id' => 3, 'prop' => 'val3'),
);
```

but in elegant way, without foreach loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In PHP 5.5:

```
$result = array_column($foo, 'prop', 'id');
```

For PHP<5.5:

```
$result = array_combine(
   array_map(function($x)
   {
      return $x['id']; 
   }, $foo),
   array_map(function($x)
   {
      return $x['prop']; 
   }, $foo),
);
```

I have to note, that despite all is *hidden* inside callbacks or even built-in functions, it's still loop inside - thus, in terms of complexity it's same as plain loop.

Answer (score -1):

For PHP < 5.5, you could also use **[array_reduce](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php)** to get the result:

```
$result = array_reduce($foo, function($v, $w) {
  $v[$w['id']] = $w['prop'];
  return $v;
});
```